# How to soften and adjust the brightness of preview and captured picture in cameraX?

Tags: android, image, brightness, android-camerax

I am using CameraX to build an photo editing app. My problem is on some devices camera preview is very sharp and dark and on few devices it is fine.
Is there any way of changing the brightness and sharpness of preview and captured picture?

Comment: Any update for this?

Comment: @user3154785 No, Nothing so far. If i find anything i'll post here

Comment: Thanks in advance :-(

Comment: @user3154785 i couldn't find a way to manipulate the preview but now i am using "PhotoEditor" library to apply filters for more information you can check this link may be you find something helpful. https://github.com/burhanrashid52/PhotoEditor

Comment: We need another solution :-(